# How to make rules for chat app using flutter and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am writting chat app with flutter, I don't know how to set the rule on firebase such only the 2 users in a group chat can write and read. This is how I store message on firebase.

```
String date = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
groupId = userId-anotherId
var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(groupId)
          .collection(groupId)
          .doc(date);
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        transaction.set(ref, {
          "senderId": userId,
          "receiverId": anotherId,
          "timestamp": date,
          'content': msg,
          "type": 'text',
        });
      });
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

- Contacting database from frontend is not the most secure way.
- If you are making this app for learning then it is fine.
- But for production app, you should add custom logic like this in your backend and connect your frontend with that API.
- Something like this.
  `Flutter app --> API --> YOUR_LOGIC --> DATABASE`

Comment: Sorry, I have little knowledge on this. Do I have to put that in the app or in the firebase console ? and how?   Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a collection of `members` for a group chat. That way you can very easy check with the rules just if a member `uid` is under the path of `groupChats/{groupID}/members/{id}`. You can even make a function for the firestoe rules like this:

```
 //Checks if user is member of group
    function isMember(groupID) {
      return  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groupChats/${groupID}/members/$(request.auth.uid)).data==true
    }
```

The databse structure would be:

```
-
groupChats
   --group1
       members
         --userUid1
         --userUid2
   --group2
       members
         --userUid2
         --userUid4
```

You can use a `boolean` or any data you want.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Although there are some details in your answer, I am having difficulty to understanding. how will the members collection be structured. In your answer, there is also groupChats, is it the same with groupId I am using?                                                              Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the structure. The groupId should be the same as you use it. GroupChats should be saved under the root path.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried several things without success. I went back to the rules I had before,  it doesn't work anymore. I get this error:  Listen for Query(target=Query(messages/aS17OHPBRgbAknBLJbTWvhz8Oyr1 - HLRS7zmA7uNUzy6kF6hUPlmGn0i2/aS17OHPBRgbAknBLJbTWvhz8Oyr1 - HLRS7zmA7uNUzy6kF6hUPlmGn0i2 order by -timestamp, -__name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.  This is the rules that was working before. match /messages/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow write, read:if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I was missing one brace in google console. My old rule is working. Still I don't know how to implement the rules as you are saying. This is the old rule: **match /messages/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow write, read:if request.auth.uid != null}**  but it is not secure.

Comment: What do you don't understand. It's not something that can fit so easy in a comment to define the structure and security rules for a goup chat system.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple. I saw in youtube. [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7xGvGAs1DQ)

This is the security rule:
match /messages/{groupChatId}/{document=**} {
allow write, read:if request.auth.uid in groupChatId.split(" - ") }